# Can't locate capture_params in newrelic.yml

Tags: newrelic

After going through the install procedures for newrelic on a Java app, the web UI recommends you to remove certain parameters from newrelic.yml, after moving configuration of these to the web UI.

https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/site/cleaning-up-your-agent-configuration-file

lists 4 sections that you need to disable:

'capture_params'
'transaction_tracer'
'error_collector'
'thread_profiler'

I was able to find and disable the last three ones but couldn't find "capture_params".

I used v3.7.2 of the agent installer.

Is this a legacy parameter and does this mean the docs should be updated? Or could there be anything wrong about my newrelic.yml file, as the capture_params section was not included there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are not able to find 'capture_params' is because this attribute has been deprecated in ver 3.7.2.  While disabling all the four parameters will be still required for older agents as described in https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/site/cleaning-up-your-agent-configuration-file, the capture_params attribute can be ignored for versions 3.7.2 and later.

The list and description of deprecated attributes can be found at https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/java/enabling-and-disabling-attributes-java